# How is a better comparison series is a duplicate of the question asking for the value of series?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[Looking for a better comparison series for reciprocal of Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111609/what-is-a-better-comparision-series-for-sum-frac-1f-n-than-sum-0-inft) is marked as duplicate of the question for the value of Fibonacci numbers.

I don't see how it is a duplicate where it is asking for just a better comparison series than $\sum 2^{-k}$

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for that isn't covered by the references in the answer to the other question.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : Yes you are right. From beginning I asked for a comparison series not the value of series.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I can't see which reference improves on $2^{-k}$ series.

Comment: The question [has been reopened](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1111609/revisions). (And I agree with that decision. I read this question as: *How can I prove that series converges? And what are some upper bounds?* To me that seems (especially the first part) different from the other question.